# std::vector<>.size() throws exception

Tags: c++, binary-tree, stdvector

i am trying to build a binary tree without pointers.
A`std::vector<NODE>nodes`holds my Nodes.
This is my node:

```
struct node {
  int bigger;
  int smaller;
  tuple data;
  std::vector<node> &nodes_ref;

  node(tuple d, std::vector<node> &nodes)
      : data(d), nodes_ref(nodes), smaller(0), bigger(0) {}

  bool insert(tuple in) {
    if (data == in)
      return false;
    else {
      if (data > in) {
        if (smaller == 0) {
          node newNode(in, nodes_ref);
          nodes_ref.push_back(newNode);
          smaller = nodes_ref.size() - 1; // This is where the program is throwing an exception
          return true;
        } else
          return nodes_ref[smaller].insert(in);
      } else {
        if (bigger == 0) {
          node newNode(in, node_ref);
          nodes_ref.push_back(newNode);
          bigger = node_ref.size() - 1;
          return true;
        } else
          return node_ref[bigger].insert(in);
```

this is tree:

```
struct tree {
  std::vector<node> nodes;

  bool insert(tuple in) {
    if (nodes.size() == 0) {
      nodes.push_back(node(in, &nodes));
      return true;
      else return nodes[0].insert(in);
    }
  }

  tree() { nodes.reserve(1000); }
}
```

the main function:

```
int main() {
  tree t;
  t.insert(tuple(2,3);
```

When `node_ref.size()` is called a exception is being thrown.
Yet everything should be fine there.
What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: `std::vector<node>&nodes_ref;` this seems to be the reason. most probably you are initializing the node with a temporary vector.

Comment: what exception?

Comment: and yes, you need to post a [MRE]. The ref binding to a temporary can be a cause, but you need to post a [MRE], otherwise we are just guessing.

Comment: What is a temporary vector ? the vector holding the nodes is in a struct vector<node> nodes[0] is the root node. i will make minimal reproducible example thx for now

Comment: the exeption was "read access violation 0xDDDDDDDDD"

Comment: 0xDDDDDDDDD marks freed heap memory in visual studio. This means you got a dangling reference. E.g. somewhere you deleted the object you are referencing here.

Comment: the heap would be freed when the vector goes out of scope right ?

Comment: 1.) `tree::insert`wont compile, look where the`else` is. 2.) node's constructor is taking a `std::vector<node> &` but you are passing `&nodes` which is a pointer. Something doesn't add up here, please double check. 3.) the heap is where you dynamically allocate things. Objects on the stack will be automatically freed.

Comment: a [mcve] should be **complete** and without syntax errors. Besides what is already mentioned in the previous comment of `churill`: For `node newNode(in, node_ref)` the `node_ref` does not exists in the shown code, only `nodes_ref`, same is for `node_ref.size() - 1` and `node_ref[bigger].insert(in)`.

Comment: If you type your code here manually instead of copying a code that compiles, then we don't know if you show everything, and what are errors because you typed it here. e.g. `node(in, &nodes)` won't compile, so either you don't show an additional constructor you have, or `&nodes` is a type and your actual code looks different. No matter what, those details are essential to be able to tell you why the code fails.

Comment: i have still to figure out how to work stackoverflow. just figured out how to copy and paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not consider whether the logic in the two functions is correct or not:

```
inline bool operator< (const tuple& lhs, const tuple& rhs) {
    if (lhs.a < rhs.a) return true;
    else if (lhs.a == rhs.a) {
        if (lhs.b < rhs.b) return true;
        else return false;
    }
}
inline bool operator> (const tuple& lhs, const tuple& rhs) {
    if (lhs.a > rhs.a) return true;
    else if (lhs.a == rhs.a) {
        if (lhs.b > rhs.b) return true;
        else return false;
    }
}
```

But these two functions will result in a compiler warning that looks something like this:

> warning: non-void function does not return a value in all control paths [-Wreturn-type]
>   [build]

So in the case that `lhs.a > rhs.a` for `operator<` or `lhs.a < rhs.a` for `operator>` those two function won't return anything from the function, and that will result into undefined behaviour.

As soon as a part of the code causes undefined behavior, any following code can cause an exception, or not predictable behavior (even if it is correct on its own), and as it is undefined behavior it could also seemingly work.

Compiler warnings are not just something you might want to fix, warnings are an information of the compiler that while it is syntactically correct it could still result in runtime errors, so you have to fix them.

So the reason why your code failed at:

```
smaller = nodes_ref.size() - 1; // This is where the program is throwing an exception
```

was most certanly not that `smaller = nodes_ref.size() - 1` itself was wrong at that point, but that the `operator >` that was called at `if (data > in) {` resulted in undefined behavior. So the exception could have been thrown at any other pointer at your code, it was just a coincidence that it happened there.

Comment: @DuckPuppy this error in `operator<` and `operator>` (or maybe another point in your code in an earlier version of your code that caused UB) is likely the reason why you had the error before at `smaller = nodes_ref.size() - 1; // This is where the program is throwing an exception`, so the reason for the exception was not at that point of the code it just happened to make it fail there, due to the UB that happened earlier. That's why it is so essential to have a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I changed nothing 
and now it works:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<ctime>
#include<random>

struct tuple
{
    int a, b;
    tuple(int a,int b):a(a),b(b){}
};
inline bool operator< (const tuple& lhs, const tuple& rhs) {
    if (lhs.a < rhs.a) return true;
    else if (lhs.a == rhs.a) {
        if (lhs.b < rhs.b) return true;
        else return false;
    }
}
inline bool operator> (const tuple& lhs, const tuple& rhs) {
    if (lhs.a > rhs.a) return true;
    else if (lhs.a == rhs.a) {
        if (lhs.b > rhs.b) return true;
        else return false;
    }
}
inline bool operator==(const tuple& lhs, const tuple& rhs) {
    if ((lhs.a == rhs.a) && (lhs.b == rhs.b)) return true;
    else return false;
}

struct node
{
    std::vector<node>& repo;
    std::uint64_t smaller;
    std::uint64_t bigger;
    tuple data;
    node(tuple d, std::vector<node>& ns) :data(d), repo(ns),smaller(0),bigger(0) { }
    bool insert(tuple in) {
        if (data == in) return false;
        else {
            if (data > in) {
                if (smaller == 0) {
                    node newNode(in, repo);
                    repo.push_back(newNode);
                    smaller = repo.size()-1;
                    return true;
                }
                else return repo.at(smaller).insert(in);
            }
            else {
                if (bigger == 0) {
                    node newNode(in, repo);
                    repo.push_back(newNode);
                    bigger = repo.size()-1;
                    return true;
                }
                else return repo[bigger].insert(in);
            }
        }
    }
};

struct tree {
    std::vector<node> nodes;
    bool insert(tuple in) {
        if (nodes.size() == 0) {
            nodes.push_back(node(in, nodes));
            return true;
        }
        else return nodes[0].insert(in);
    }
    tree() {
        nodes.reserve(1000);
    }
};

int main()
{
    tree t;
    //std::default_random_engine rng(time(NULL));
    //std::uniform_int_distribution<std::uint32_t> dis(0, 3);

    t.insert(tuple(2, 3));
    t.insert(tuple(2, 1));
    t.insert(tuple(3, 8));
}
```

Yesterday i thought i was going insane over this.
What reason could there be for things like this happening ?
i had trouble with windows defender blocking my programs from running yesterday.
a whole lot of noise about nothing.
seems like it.

Comment: Thats how your [mcve] should have looked like. `I changed nothing and now it works`: well, `nodes.push_back(node(in, nodes));` is different to `nodes.push_back(node(in, &nodes));` and the other mentioned parts. And that your code runs right now for you, and does not throw an exception does mean that it is valid. Your code can e.g. cause undefined behavior for `operator<` and  `operator>` and in fact does for `operator>` right now. For me it throws an exception due to that.

Answer (score 0):

now it will work in all cases:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<ctime>
#include<random>

struct tuple
{
    std::uint32_t a, b;
    tuple(int a,int b):a(a),b(b){}
};
inline bool operator< (const tuple& lhs, const tuple& rhs) {
    if (lhs.a < rhs.a) return true;
    else if (lhs.a == rhs.a) {
        if (lhs.b < rhs.b) return true;
        else return false;
    }
    return false;
}
inline bool operator> (const tuple& lhs, const tuple& rhs) {
    if (lhs.a > rhs.a) return true;
    else if (lhs.a == rhs.a) {
        if (lhs.b > rhs.b) return true;
        else return false;
    }
    return false;
}
inline bool operator==(const tuple& lhs, const tuple& rhs) {
    if ((lhs.a == rhs.a) && (lhs.b == rhs.b)) return true;
    else return false;
}

struct node
{
    std::vector<node>& repo;
    std::uint64_t smaller;
    std::uint64_t bigger;
    tuple data;
    node(tuple d, std::vector<node>& ns) :data(d), repo(ns),smaller(0),bigger(0) { }
    bool insert(tuple in) {
        if (data == in) return false;
        else {
            if (data > in) {
                if (smaller == 0) {
                    node newNode(in, repo);
                    repo.push_back(newNode);
                    smaller = repo.size()-1;
                    return true;
                }
                else return repo.at(smaller).insert(in);
            }
            else {
                if (bigger == 0) {
                    node newNode(in, repo);
                    repo.push_back(newNode);
                    bigger = repo.size()-1;
                    return true;
                }
                else return repo[bigger].insert(in);
            }
        }
    }
};

struct tree {
    std::vector<node> nodes;
    bool insert(tuple in) {
        if (nodes.size() == 0) {
            nodes.push_back(node(in, nodes));
            return true;
        }
        else return nodes[0].insert(in);
    }
    tree() {
        nodes.reserve(1000);
    }
};


int main()
{
    tree t;
    std::default_random_engine rng(time(NULL));
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::uint32_t> dis(0, 9);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) t.insert(tuple(dis(rng), dis(rng)));

}
```

thanks @t.niese